# MSWC.BrowserType on IIS 8.5 always returns "Unknown" as Platform and "Default" as Browser

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8, browscap

We recently moved an old Classic ASP website to a newer Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8.5. After this switch, `MSWC.BrowserType` can no longer get the browser or platform of a user.

On a test page, I have the following code:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%Option Explicit%>

<%
    Dim browserdetect

    Set browserdetect = Server.CreateObject("MSWC.BrowserType")

    if isObject(browserdetect) then
       response.write("The object was created!<br>")
    else
       response.write("The object was not created")
    end if

    Response.Write("Platform = " & browserdetect.Platform & "<br>")
    Response.Write("Browser = " & browserdetect.Browser & "<br>") 
%>
```

This returns:

```
The object was created!
Platform = unknown
Browser = Default
```

I do have the latest `browscap.ini` in `c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` on the server. Do I need to do anything else for this to work?

Comment: See this thread on IIS forums - https://forums.iis.net/t/1148429.aspx

Comment: Make sure you put the file in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv`. If the application pool running your app is 32-bit, `browscap.ini` will be searched in this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kul-Tigin pointed out in the comment above, if the application pool running your app is 32-bit (which it was, in my case) browscap.ini will be searched in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv`.

I had previously copied the `browscap.ini`to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`, exactly as I always had done on the old server.